# Redirect one folder to another, using .htaccess, but retain original URL and block access to all other folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

**tl;dr** *How can redirect `http://test.lab.example.com/mech-platform/` (a non-existing folder) to `http://test.lab.example.com/mech-platform-web/frontend/web/` (an existing folder), using *.htaccess* file in Apache, so that user still sees the original URL in browser, cannot access anything else on this server and that such redirect is not permanent (not cached by the browser)?*

---

#### The problem

I have a *test.lab.example.com* domain which points to an IP address which points to `htdocs` folder in my Apache installation. There I have an existing folder of `mech-platform-web/frontend/web`, which is web-accessible entry folder for my application.

I want to use a "fake" (non-existing) folder or URL part within that domain:

```
http://test.lab.example.com/mech-platform/
```

to point to above mentioned folder:

```
http://test.lab.example.com/mech-platform-web/frontend/web/
```

All files in `web` folder, all subfolders and sub-parts of URL as good as all query items must be rewritten and processed. No other folders or files, above this web-accessible folder, must be accessible at all.

The redirection or rewrite should be invisible to the end-user. So for example all calls to "fake" URL / folder:

```
http://test.lab.example.com/mech-platform/device/edit/1
http://test.lab.example.com/mech-platform/index.php?device=1&op=edit
```

Must be processed over the existing one:

```
http://test.lab.example.com/mech-platform-web/frontend/web/device/edit/1
http://test.lab.example.com/mech-platform-web/frontend/web/index.php?device=1&op=edit
```

The redirection or rewrite must be non-permanent. Meaning that the browser reading it must not cache it. If I remove *.htaccess* file from my web-root (`http://test.lab.example.com/`) the redirection or rewrite must be stopped. And any browser accessing `http://test.lab.example.com/mech-platform/` must hit the wall with 404 (after *.htaccess* folder removal) since this folder does not exists in reality.

###An attempt for a solution

I am a total newbie to Apache configuration or mod-rewrite, so all that I managed to achieve so far is to copy-paste modified solutions found in SO, adjust them and find them not working.

For example, I have tried this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/mech-platform/(.*)$ $1/mech-platform-web/frontend/web/$2 [R,L]
```

Which failed totally ("The requested URL was not found on this server").

I have also tried the following one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.\lab\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://test.lab.example.com/mech-platform/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ mech-platform-web/frontend/web [L]
```

This one fails with "Internal server error".

By a complete accident I have tried the above with "test" subdoman / part removed.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lab\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://lab.example.com/mech-platform/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ mech-platform-web/frontend/web [L]
```

For the expected URL of `http://lab.example.com/mech-platform/` it again throw "Internal server error". While when trying to access the subdomain as whole -- `http://lab.example.com/` -- I am getting redirected to the correct subfolder of `mech-platform-web/frontend/web`.

However this must be a product of some error / misunderstanding. And in addition it produces permanent redirection (browser caches it and reuses even if *.htaccess* file is removed from server). And it make it non-invisible. User can all the time see `mech-platform-web/frontend/web` folder and even access folders above (like `mech-platform-web/frontend` or `mech-platform-web`. Which is total failure in terms of security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following rule should work for you in site root .htaccess:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.lab\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mech-platform/(.*) mech-platform-web/frontend/web/$1 [NC,L]
```

If you want to block all other files and folders from visitors then add this rule in the end:

```bash
RewriteRule !^(mech-platform-web/|$) [NC,F]
```

This rule will do silent rewrite and will stop working as soon as you remove this .htaccess or comment out this rule.

Comment: After testing, this seems to be a brilliant solution, thank you. Two questions or asks. (1) Can you extend this solution to cover also IP addresses and _localhost_? I have tried to copy your code from first example, but using `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10\.2\.2\.30$ [NC]` is not working. (2) The redirection / rewrite works great, but when my application is run all the links inside points to `mech-platform-web/frontend/web/` not to `mech-platform/`. My app has all links generated based on what request returns as BASE_URL. A my correct that I need Virtual Host in Apache to truly "replace" URLs?

Comment: Why are you trying `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10\.2\.2\.30$ [NC]`? If subdomain `test.lab.example.com` is configured in `VirtualHost then use that instead of IP address

Comment: At this moment, I have no virtual host defined at all. That's why I am asking, if the above is achievable through .htaccess or virtual hosts only or something else.

Comment: Some hosting providers provide you a CPANEL where you can create and configure subdomains like `test.lab.example.com` thus saving you hassle of creating `VirtualHost`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Unfortunately, this is a scenario where I have only a domain configuration that points to my local server. The server is based on Windows, so I cannot install / use neither cPanel nor any Linux-based domain tools. All I have is domains and subdomains configuration provided by domain operator and my own Apache configuration.